# What is the equivalent of a prototypical Manipulate in lower level functions?

Tags: programming, dynamic, manipulate

**Background:** In the Mathematica tutorial ['Dynamic Interactivity'](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/DynamicInteractivity/) I read that there is a way of developing GUIs in Mathematica that do not use `Manipulate`. I want to investigate this further.

**Question:** What is the equivalent of `Manipulate[i,{i,1,5,1}]` in 'lower-level' Mathematica functions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Start from

```
{Slider[Dynamic[x], {1, 5, 1}], Dynamic[x]}
```

[image]

Next localize control variable:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, {Slider[Dynamic[x], {1, 5, 1}], Dynamic[x]}]
```

[image]

And add some interface elements:

```
Panel@DynamicModule[{x},  Column[{Slider[Dynamic[x], 
{1, 5, 1}], Panel[Dynamic[x], ImageSize -> 200]}]]
```

[image]

Add even more

```
Panel@DynamicModule[{x},   Column[{Row[{"x", Spacer[10], 
Animator[Dynamic[x], {1, 5, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False, 
ImageSize -> Small]}], Panel[Dynamic[x], ImageSize -> 235]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea to build-up your answer like that.

Comment: +1, though there is one thing it's missing: the Bookmarks/Autorun icon from the upper right corner. I have no idea how to replicate that.

Comment: +1 I guess replicating `SaveDefinitions` and "Paste Snapshot" would be difficult as well?

Answer (score 10):

I realize this isn't what you meant by "lower level" but nevertheless viewing the [Cell Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/ShowExpression.html) for various kinds of output can be interesting and informative.  Based on observing that expression it is possible to craft this:

```
DynamicBox[
  Manipulate`ManipulateBoxes[1, StandardForm, 
   "Variables" :> {a$$ = 0},
   "ControllerVariables" :> {Hold[a$$, 0]}, 
   "OtherVariables" :> {}, 
   "Body" :> Plot[Sin[x (1 + a$$ x)], {x, 0, 6}], 
   "Specifications" :> {{a$$, 0, 2}},
   "Options" :> {}, 
   "DefaultOptions" :> {}
  ]
] // ToExpression
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course direct use like this isn't advisable because I have stripped out all localization etc. for this example that is normally generated automatically.

---

As a further point of curiosity, if you want to see the *very* low level Box expressions, leave off `DynamicBox` and `ToExpression` from the example above to reveal this:

```
PaneBox[PanelBox[
  DynamicWrapperBox[
   GridBox[{{ItemBox[
       ItemBox[StyleBox[
         GridBox[{{TagBox["a", HoldForm], 
            TagBox[PaneBox[
              DynamicModuleBox[{Typeset`open$$ = False, 
                Typeset`paused$$ = 0, Typeset`rate$$ = Automatic, 
                Typeset`dir$$ = Forward}, 
               StyleBox[
                DynamicBox[
                 FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", 
                   "Manipulator04"][Dynamic[a$$], 
                  Dynamic[a$$], {0, 2}, Medium, Small, Automatic, 
                  True, Automatic, False, True, True, All, False, {}, 
                  Dynamic[Typeset`open$$], Dynamic[Typeset`paused$$], 
                  Dynamic[Typeset`rate$$], Dynamic[Typeset`dir$$]]], 
                DynamicUpdating -> True], 
               DynamicModuleValues -> Automatic], ImageMargins -> 0, 
              BaselinePosition -> Baseline], 
             Manipulate`InterpretManipulator[
              Dynamic[a$$], {0, 2}, {ContinuousAction -> True, 
               AutoAction -> False}]]}}, AutoDelete -> False, 
          GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, 
            "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}, 
          ColumnAlignments -> {Right, Left}], "ManipulateLabel", 
         StripOnInput -> False], Alignment -> {Automatic, Inherited}, 
        StripOnInput -> False], Background -> None, 
       StripOnInput -> False]}, {ItemBox[
       TagBox[StyleBox[PaneBox[DynamicBox[ToBoxes[Refresh[\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"Plot", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Sin", "[", 
RowBox[{"x", " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", "+", 
RowBox[{"a$$", " ", "x"}]}], ")"}]}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"x", ",", "0", ",", "6"}], "}"}]}], "]"}],
Identity,
Editable->True,
Selectable->True]\), TrackedSymbols -> Full], StandardForm], 
           SynchronousUpdating -> Automatic], ImageMargins -> 10], 
         Deployed -> False, ScriptLevel -> 0, 
         GraphicsBoxOptions -> {PreserveImageOptions -> True}, 
         Graphics3DBoxOptions -> {PreserveImageOptions -> True}, 
         StripOnInput -> False], Identity, Selectable -> False, 
        Editable -> False], Alignment -> {Left, Center}, 
       Background -> GrayLevel[1], Frame -> 1, 
       FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0, 0.2], ItemSize -> Automatic, 
       StripOnInput -> False]}}, AutoDelete -> False, 
    GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, 
      "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}, ColumnAlignments -> Left, 
    GridFrame -> False, GridFrameMargins -> 1, RowSpacings -> 2, 
    RowAlignments -> Top], 
   If[CurrentValue["SelectionOver"], 
    Manipulate`Dump`ReadControllerState[(Manipulate`Dump`updateOneVar[\
#1, CurrentValue["PreviousFormatTime"], 
         CurrentValue[
          "CurrentFormatTime"]] &) /@ {Manipulate`Dump`controllerLink[
        a$$, "X1", If["DefaultAbsolute", True, "JB1"], False, {0, 2}, 
        1.]}, CurrentValue[{"ControllerData", {"Gamepad", "Joystick", 
        "Multi-Axis Controller"}}], {}]]], DefaultBaseStyle -> {}, 
  FrameMargins -> {{5, 5}, {5, 5}}], ImageMargins -> 0, 
 BaselinePosition -> Automatic]
```

I am rather glad we don't have to do "low level" FrontEnd programming very often!