# Understanding evaluation and typesetting

Tags: front-end, evaluation, output-formatting, conversion, boxes

---

#### Background

So, one could be surprised by the fact that:

```
Hold @ Grid[{{1, 2}}]
 (*or*)
Hold @ Graphics @ Disk[]
```

[image]

This issue and methods of prevention are discussed in [Prevent graphics render inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32296/5478).

**I need further explanation though.**

---

#### Questions

> Recall that the rendering of Graphics has nothing to do with evaluation. It is done entirely in typesetting. And therefore, a robust solution will treat this as a problem of typesetting, and not as a problem of evaluation. - [John Fultz answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32314/5478)

- **Question 1** What is the typesetting in Mathematica? What procedures does it include?
- **Question 2** Why isn't `MakeBoxes` using custom rules called `Evaluation`?

  I understand that

  ```
  Hold @ RawBoxes @ GraphicsBox[DiskBox[{0, 0}]]
  ```

  Will be displayed as a black disk, FrontEnd taking care of `GraphicsBox` is natural.

  But I don't know why this is done this way:

  ```
  MakeBoxes @ Graphics[Disk[]]   
    (*GraphicsBox[DiskBox[{0, 0}]]*)

  MakeBoxes @ Whatever[Disk[]] (*expected*)
    (*RowBox[{"Whatever", "[", RowBox[{"Disk", "[", "]"}], "]"}]*)
  ```

  **For me using custom translations while parsing input is more than just typesetting**.
- **Question 3** Why this design choice? Couldn't `Grid`, `Graphics` just **evaluate** to `GraphicsBox`? (what would allow `Hold` to prevent rendering)

---

Except of confusion this makes working with

```
InputField[Dynamic@x, Hold[Expression]]
```

pointless. Because as soon as you type something with custom `MakeBoxes` rules you will have to retype that to edit.

Am I overreacting? Have I missed something that makes this behavior really appreciated?

Comment: The whole point of `Graphics` is that it is an inert representation of graphics.   Since version 6, it doesn't evaluate, it doesn't do anything, etc.  It just *represents* graphics.  The front end then can show it as text, but it can also show it as an image.  Both are just ways to display the same Mathematica expressions. In StandardForm it shows it as an image and in InputForm as text.

Comment: I don't know, maybe we're thinking of this in very different ways or I just don't understand your question, but this behaviour makes perfect sense to me.  It seems like a very elegant way to add graphics capability to a system that prefers to avoid side effects: just use declarative graphics, and render the graphics expression automatically.

Comment: @Szabolcs It's not only about `Graphics` but whatever that has specific rules for `MakeBoxes`. As I said, I understand `RawBoxes@GraphicsBox[DiskBox[{0, 0}]]` is meant to be a picture. I just don't understand why `Graphics`,without evaluation, is converted to `GraphicsBox` instead of `RowBox "Graphics" "[" ...`. I don't claim I'm right. Maybe I'm missing something, well obviously I am missing something, that's why there is a question.

Comment: @Szabolcs also, "disabling" specific `MakeBoxes` still allows you to write `GraphicsBox` and see images without evaluation. So the behavior I'm talking about is nothing more but shortcut which generates problems. In my opinion, but still, I am rather asking for explanation than complaining :)

Comment: I think that the answer to question 2 is that evaluation means something specific here. In the entire process of producing formatted/rendered output from an expression in an evaluated cell, it makes sense to call the initial handling of the expression by the kernel the "evaluation" phase. Afterwards, things get converted to boxes and then get rendered. I think the fact that in the step of "conversion to boxes" expressions with head `MakeBoxes` are also evaluated, leads to confusion.

Comment: @Karsten 7. Why have you deleted your answer? It doesn't answer the essence of the question but provides good workarounds for the `InputField` issue. I think it is worth to keep it as a partial answer demonstrating that the problem with `InputField` resulting from the described design choices is not so severe as one can imagine...

Answer (score 10):

### **Question 1:**

> What is the typesetting in Mathematica? What procedures does it include?

I think that [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Jan/msg00427.html) 2008 year MathGroup post by [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/309/john-fultz) completely answers this question, so I'll cite it here:

> In version 6, the kernel has absolutely no involvement whatsoever in
>   generating the rendered  image.  The steps taken in displaying a
>   graphic in version 6 are very much like  those used in displaying
>   non-graphical output.  It works as follows:
>
> 1) The expression is evaluated, and ultimately produces something with
>   head `Graphics[]` or `Graphics3D[]`.
>
> 2) The resulting expression is passed through `MakeBoxes`. `MakeBoxes`
>   has a set of rules which turns the graphics expression into the box
>   language which the front  end uses to represent graphics. E.g.,
>
> ```
> In[9]:= MakeBoxes[Graphics[{Point[{0, 0}]}], StandardForm]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > Out[9]= GraphicsBox[{PointBox[{0, 0}]}]
> > ```
>
> Internally, we call this the "typeset" expression.  It may be a little
>   weird thinking of graphics as being "typeset", but it's fundamentally
>   the same  operation which happens for typesetting (which has worked
>   this way for 11  years), so I'll use the term.
>
> 3) The resulting typeset expression is sent via MathLink to the front
>   end.
>
> 4) The front end parses the typeset expression and creates internal
>   objects which generally have a one-to-one correspondence to the
>   typeset expression.
>
> 5) The front end renders the internal objects.
>
> In version 6, the front end, and only the front end can render
>   graphics (unless  you use the legacy PostScript scheme via
>   `` <<Version5`Graphics` ``, in which the kernel does the hard job of
>   rendering the graphic to a simple subset of  PostScript, and the FE
>   has the considerably easier job of merely rendering the  PostScript to
>   the screen).

---

### **Question 2:**

> But I don't know why this is done this way:
>
> ```
> MakeBoxes @ Graphics[Disk[]]   
>   (*GraphicsBox[DiskBox[{0, 0}]]*)
>
> MakeBoxes @ Whatever[Disk[]] (*expected*)
>   (*RowBox[{"Whatever", "[", RowBox[{"Disk", "[", "]"}], "]"}]*)
> ```

This is because typesetting rules are applied in a chain where the choices of branches depend of the previous choices (which in the first place are determined by the parent `Head`s). Citing the Documentation for [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html) (emphasis is mine):

> `MakeBoxes` is **NOT** automatically called on the results it generates.
>   This means that explicit `MakeBoxes` calls must typically be inserted
>   into definitions that are given.

We can `Trace` the typesetting and see what actually happens:

```
ExportString[
 Trace[MakeBoxes@Graphics[Disk[]], Typeset`MakeBoxes, TraceInternal -> True], "Text"]
```

> ```
> "{{{HoldForm[Typeset`MakeBoxes[Graphics[Disk[]], StandardForm, Graphics]], 
>    HoldForm[Typeset`ReleaseHold[System`Dump`InheritAmbientSettings[
>       With[{System`Dump`boxes = Typeset`MakeBoxes[Disk[], StandardForm, 
>           Graphics], System`Dump`options = System`Dump`GraphicsOptionsToBoxes[
>           {}, StandardForm, Graphics]}, GraphicsBox[System`Dump`boxes, 
>         System`Dump`options]], Graphics]]], 
>    {{{{HoldForm[Typeset`MakeBoxes[Disk[], StandardForm, Graphics]], 
>        HoldForm[DiskBox[{0, 0}]]}}}}}}}"
> ```

From the above we see that when the `Head` of expression is `Graphics` the call to `MakeBoxes` is redirected to `` Typeset`MakeBoxes `` with `Graphics` as the third argument. But without the head `Graphics` there is no call to `` Typeset`MakeBoxes `` and everything is handled by `MakeBoxes`:

```
Trace[MakeBoxes@Whatever[Disk[]], TraceInternal -> True]
```

> ```
> {HoldForm[MakeBoxes[Whatever[Disk[]]]], 
>  {HoldForm[MakeBoxes[Whatever, StandardForm]], HoldForm["Whatever"]}, 
>  {HoldForm[MakeBoxes[Disk[], StandardForm]], 
>   {HoldForm[MakeBoxes[Disk, StandardForm]], HoldForm["Disk"]}, 
>   HoldForm[RowBox[{"Disk", "[", "]"}]]}, 
>  HoldForm[RowBox[{"Whatever", "[", RowBox[{"Disk", "[", "]"}], "]"}]]}
> ```

---

### **Question 3:**

> Why this design choice? Couldn't `Grid`, `Graphics` just **evaluate** to `GraphicsBox`? (what would allow `Hold` to prevent rendering)

Of course such question should best be answered by the developers but I think that a part of the answer is already clear from the "Question 2" section: parsing of expression into BoxForms (i.e. typesetting) is not intended to be a 1-to-1 operation, interpretation of a language construct depends on its neighborhood (especially on the parent expression in which it is embedded). Of course it is already a design choice but from this choice follows that typesetting cannot be done via `OwnValues`. And as [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) correctly points out in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114374/280), it would be very inconvenient from practical point of view if the expressions given in the high-level *Mathematica* language would automatically evaluated into their low-level BoxForm representation during usual process of working with them in the WL. I'm also glad that the most of the time in the WL we work only with the short and predictable high-level representation. At the same time, the language allows to control the process of conversion into BoxForms if it is strictly needed and it is also easy to prevent rendering of `Graphics` without loosing the ability to render it later, some ideas you can take from my [`shortInputForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function and [the original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6224185/590388) when the first version of this function was developed, and the `MakeBoxesStop` function by Leonid Shifrin from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6534071/590388) can also be of interest for you:

```
MakeBoxesStop[Graphics[Disk[]]]
```

> ```
> Graphics[Disk[List[0, 0]]]
> ```

---

### The `InputField` issue

> Except of confusion this makes working with
>
> ```
> InputField[Dynamic@x, Hold[Expression]]
> ```
>
> pointless. Because as soon as you type something with custom
>   `MakeBoxes` rules you will have to retype that to edit.

The reason for this is that the contents of the input field is rendered in `StandardForm` when the value of `Dynamic` variable `x` is changed (including the situation when you change it via the `InputField` itself, i.e. by typing and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

As a simple workaround I can suggest to work with `String`, then convert it into expression using `MakeExpression`. You can include the syntax checking into `InputField` for example as follows:

```
InputField[Dynamic@x, String, Background -> Dynamic[If[SyntaxQ@x, Yellow, Red]]]
```

Now for syntactically correct WL expressions the input field will become yellow, but for incorrect it will become red.

Another workaround is suggested by [Karsten 7.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18476/karsten-7) in [his (now deleted) answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114316/280): `InputField` allows to work with raw boxes when the second argument is `Boxes`. When working with raw boxes you keep the same predictable and stable behavior of the input field as in the case of working with string input but allowed to use 2D formatting, paste already rendered images and other objects. What is significant, the appearance of the input field won't change after you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and hence you won't have to retype anything!

```
Grid[{{"InputField", 
   "Converted to HeldExpression in InputForm"}, {InputField[Dynamic[x], Boxes, 
    BaseStyle -> "Input"], Dynamic[InputForm@ToExpression[x, StandardForm, Hold]]}}, 
 Frame -> All]
```

> [image: output]

Answer (score 5):

I am going to attempt to answer your questions off the cuff.  I have been somewhat inactive on this site recently and also not using *Mathematica* much, so I am surely not at my best, so "take this with a grain of salt" as they say.

- **Question 1** What is the typesetting in Mathematica? What procedures does it include?

Typesetting is anything that is done for or by the Front End that is not part of Kernel evaluation, e.g. conversion to Box form.  It certainly can entail Kernel evaluation, but if this evaluation takes place for the purpose of conversion to Box form it may be considered typesetting.

- **Question 2** Why isn't `MakeBoxes` using custom rules called `Evaluation`?

Of course there is evaluation involved as noted above but it seems useful to discriminate between evaluation that takes place directly on behalf of the program and that which takes place on behalf of the Front End interface.

- **For me using custom translations while parsing input is more than just typesetting**.

You are free to make that distinction, however it seems equally reasonable to consider input processing with `$PreRead` etc. as distinct from main evaluation.  Additional specificity is required if we wish to discuss multiple forms of evaluation.

- **Question 3** Why this design choice? Couldn't `Grid`, `Graphics` just **evaluate** to `GraphicsBox`? (what would allow `Hold` to prevent rendering)

I cannot speak for the designers but I am quite glad that they did not do what you suggest!  Box form is normally *not* something that an average user works with directly; it is almost a language unto itself that it used by the Front End for interface purposes.  It would be quite confusing and arduous if we had to work with Box form any time we wished to operate on `Graphics` etc. code.

Consider the example I gave in answer to [What is the equivalent of a prototypical Manipulate in lower level functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4878/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-prototypical-manipulate-in-lower-level-functions/4885#4885) and imagine if a simple `Slider` directly evaluated into the full Box form in the lower part of that post.  As I said there: **I am rather glad we don't have to do "low level" FrontEnd programming very often!**