# Understanding the output formatting of held forms

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting, formatting, hold

When a `HoldComplete` expression reaches the frontend, there will *still* be evaluation happening *within* it, namely for all expressions that have `FormatValues`.

For example

```
Format[myx, StandardForm] = "somethingelse";
HoldComplete@myx
```

displays as

```
HoldComplete[somethingelse]
```

If I choose another `Form` for which I have not defined `FormatValues`, the formatting is not applied:

```
OutputForm@HoldComplete@myx
```

> `HoldComplete[myx]`

Interestingly, `SparseArray[{}, {2, 2}]` displays differently from `HoldComplete@SparseArray[{}, {2, 2}]` (which stays unchanged) and I have not been able to find the `...Form` that would format the `SparseArray` while inside `HoldComplete`. I have tried

```
Through[(Symbol /@ Names["System`*Form"])@
  HoldComplete@SparseArray[{}, {2, 2}]]
```

They must be using an internal codepath for that.

I'm also a bit surprised that many `Form`s besides `StandardForm` display `HoldComplete@myx` as `HoldComplete[somethingelse]`, try

```
Through[(Symbol /@ Names["System`*Form"])@HoldComplete[myx]]
```

What's bitten me is also that `Manipulate` inside `HoldComplete` are evaluated:

```
HoldComplete[Manipulate[0, {x, Abort[]}]]
```

gives

```
$Aborted[]
```

(interestingly, `StandardForm@HoldComplete[Manipulate[0, {x, Abort[]}]]` gives `$Aborted` without the extra `[]`).

The workarounds seem to be to apply any of `ToString`, `FullForm`, `OutputForm`, `InputForm`...

On a final note: `FormatValues` of `Manipulate` shows a rule for `MakeBoxes` -- I thought you are supposed to define output formats by modifying `Format[x, form]`?!

---

Where can I learn more about output formatting and format time evaluations?

I found ref/Format, tutorial/DefiningOutputFormats and maybe tutorial/FormattedOutput. Anything else?

**Aside** I just noticed that *all* `FormatValues` report rules for `MakeBoxes`...

Comment: Strongly related if not a duplicate: "[Conversion of expressions by the FrontEnd](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5617685/590388)."

Comment: If I got you well, it is not "evaluation" in its specifinc WL meaning but typesetting (which uses the same mechanism) and this topic is at least closely related: [Understanding evaluation and typesetting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114305/5478).