# Why does `Times` evaluate within `Hold` when doing replacement?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, replacement

```
Hold @ t[t[1,1],2]/.t-> Times
Hold @ t[t[1,2],2]/.t-> Times
```

> ```
> Hold[(1 1) 2]
> Hold[2 2]
> ```

Why doesn't the second one give `Hold[(1 2) 2]`?
It seems to have to do with `1` appearing in there.

`Hold @ t[t[2,2],2]/.t-> Times` gives `Hold[(2 2) 2]` but

`Hold @ t[t[2,2],1]/.t-> Times` gives `Hold[2 2]`

The result is the same if I do the replacement with `:>` or `//.` or using `With` or a global replacement rule (function).

Maybe the default value of `Times`, `1`, is being used in these replacements? Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 7):

This is a specific case of a more general topic: [**Understanding evaluation and typesetting**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114305/5478)

It is not a bug, nothing is evaluated. Why then `Times'` "special" formatting is recognized for nested `t[t[1,2],2]` as it would have been evaluated?

It is because of special formatting rules defined for `Times` (any symbol in general). Also certain `Attributes` affect pattern-matching which is performed during formatting/typesetting (`Format`/`MakeBoxes`).

```
ClearAll[h];

SetAttributes[h, Orderless]
Format[h[1, x__]] := Row[{x}]

Hold @ t[t[2, 1], 2] /. t -> h

% // FullForm
```

> ```
> Hold[h[2,2]]
>
> Hold[h[h[2,1],2]]
> ```

Of course for `Times` more rules are defined, it is only a small example to show the point.

---

> `Flat`is an attribute that can be assigned to a symbol `f` to indicate that all expressions involving nested functions `f` should be flattened out. **This property is accounted for in pattern matching.**
>
> `Orderless` [...]. This property is accounted for in pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

This is purely a formatting "issue":
[image]

Comment: Can we consider this a bug still?

Comment: Isn't the `FullForm` unsurprisingly correct?  That's what I go to, when the typeset form seems to vary from my expectation.

Comment: @masterxilo. No