# Custom MakeBoxes rule triggered in the Information of functions

Tags: evaluation, boxes

Consider the following toy example:

```
prepareBoxes[foo[expr_]] := 
  message["The argument was " <> ToString@expr];

MakeBoxes[foo[expr_], StandardForm] := ToBoxes@prepareBoxes@foo[expr]
```

Evaluating `foo[2]` then gives the expected result:

```
foo[2]
(* message["The argument was 2"] *)
```

But if I want to review the definition of `foo` with `Information` I get the following:

[image]

Notice how the custom `MakeBoxes` gets evaluated on the LHS of the definition of `prepareBoxes`.
This is weird enough, and arguably not the wanted result, but it may still be fine.

The problem arises if the definition of `prepareBoxes` is slightly different:

```
prepareBoxes[foo[expr_Integer]] := 
  message["The argument was " <> ToString@expr];
MakeBoxes[foo[expr_], StandardForm] := ToBoxes@prepareBoxes@foo[expr]
```

where I just changed the definition of `prepareBoxes` to only trigger when the input is an `Integer`.
Evaluating `Information` on `prepareBoxes` with this definition we get an infinite recursion, for the same reason we got the wrong evaluation in the case above:

[image]

Is this behaviour considerable as a feature? It can be quite annoying in many occasions.

Is it avoidable? If so, how?

Comment: closely related: [Understanding evaluation and typesetting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114305/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what `ToBoxes@prepareBoxes[foo[expr]]` does when `prepareBoxes[foo[expr]]` does not actually evaluate to anything (because you have a literal `expr` instead of, say, `2`).  It makes something like

```
RowBox[{"prepareBoxes", "[", ..., "]"}]
```

But what goes in place of the `...`?  Of course `ToBoxes` has to translate `foo[expr]`, for which it has to invoke `MakeBoxes[foo[expr]]`.  And there you have the recursion.

You get a recursion when you evaluate `foo[expr]` (with `expr` a symbol).  More precisely, you get a recursion *when the result of this evaluation is typeset*, as `MakeBoxes` is invoked only then.  Displaying the definition causes similar things (in this case `foo[expr_Integer]`) to be typeset, thus also cause a recursion.

The proper way to deal with this is to restrict the pattern in the `MakeBoxes` definition (not in `prepareBoxes`).

```
foo /: MakeBoxes[foo[expr_Integer], StandardForm] := ...
```

Don't forget to clear your existing definitions first.

---

This is a very common beginner mistake when creating `MakeBoxes` definitions.  I fell into this trap multiple times.

Comment: I think it's better to use `TagSetDelayed` as well, so something like `foo /: MakeBoxes[foo[expr_Integer], StandardForm] := ...`.

Comment: @CarlWoll I thought that the definition is associated with `foo` anyway, but you are correct: it is associated with `MakeBoxes`. Is there any reason I should use `foo` as the tag other than that then `ClearAll[foo]` would clear this too?

Comment: I haven't thought carefully about the issue of `UpValues` of `foo` vs `DownValues` of `MakeBoxes`, but a couple reasons that come to mind are speed and code portability/readability. Using `UpValues` means that `MakeBoxes` for non-`foo` expressions should be unaffected. Also, if you use `DownValues`, then things like `??foo`, `Definition[foo]`, `Save[file, foo]` and ``Language`ExtendedDefinition["foo"]`` will not have those rules. I would prefer to have `??foo` and the others contain all `foo` rules.