# How to Hold a Form function

Tags: formatting, hold

For Example

```
Hold[HoldForm[FullForm[x]]]
```

`Out[1]=Hold[\!\(\* TagBox[ TagBox[ StyleBox["x", ShowSpecialCharacters->False, ShowStringCharacters->True, NumberMarks->True], FullForm], HoldForm]\)]`

It is as if "Hold" evaluated Forms first, there's almost nothing that can stop the evaluation of MatrixForms, I've tried: Hold, HoldAll, Inactivate, HoldForm.

Surprisingly
`ToBoxes[MatrixForm[x] // FullForm][[1, 1]]` Appers to "Hold" the result better than `Hold`

Comment: HoldForm[__] is prints its content even inside Hold. Try `Hold[HoldForm[FullForm[x]]] // FullForm`

Comment: I must admit mathematica evaluation is very confusing, but this solved it for this small example

Comment: I've been there, does it address your problem?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114305/5478

Comment: @Kuba wow, that's a lot! Thank you.